# Reading large files in XCode using PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm currently writing an iOS app using the PhoneGap 2.0 API.

I am using the FileReader() class to try to read the contents of a file, with size 139KB, but it gets about half way through reading the file and then XCode and the Simulator crashes.  Is there a better way to store this data or to read the file?

The data stored in the file is currently in JSON format.

Thanks

Comment: It would be good to show us the crash log.

Comment: Where can I find the crash log? I have searched and can't seem to find it in the normal places. I'm still looking though.

Comment: When it crashes it should give you an error in the console in XCode.

Comment: There is no error message. When it reads the contents of the file, it shows what it has read in the console. So it stops mid-stream, roughly half way through the file, and the only thing I can see in the console is text that it has read most recently.  I can't navigate through the console as XCode crashes and I have to Force Quit.  Is there another way? Here is a link to the output: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7016827/output.png As you see, it just stops reading the file with no error message. (I'm reading it as a DataUrl at the moment, but reading as Text has the same effect.)

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to read the file?

Comment: Sure.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7016827/code.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem - added in

```
 reader.onerror= function(evt) {console.log(evt.target.error.code);}
    reader.error= function(evt) {console.log(evt.target.error.code);}
```

and no longer crashes takes a long time - not sure if this the debugger writing to console?